# Accessing nested hash map in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have a flat data structure in csv format that I have turned into a hash whereby set a key on one of the column in the file...so we have key_1, key_2, Key_3, each key has the associated values for the associated row

This is a example of the flat file...

```
key     book  id    ccy  mtm      161205 161206 161207 161208 161209
key_1   abc   123   usd  2000000  -5045  600    494    -2646  -231
key_2   abc   124   gbp  -150000  5178   20669  -1871  214    22251
key_3   abc   125   eur  1908055  -23279 -730   -513   -19933 -21555
```

And this is it after I create the hash...

```
{"key_1"=>
   [{:book=>"abc",
     :trade_id=>"123",
     :ccy=>"usd",
     :mtm=>2000000,
     :"161205"=>-5045,
     :"161206"=>600,
     :"161207"=>494,
     :"161208"=>-2646,
     :"161209"=>-231}],
"key_2"=>
   [{:book=>"abc",
     :trade_id=>"124",
     :ccy=>"gbp",
     :mtm=>-150000,
     :"161205"=>5178,
     :"161206"=>20669,
     :"161207"=>-18771,
     :"161208"=>214,
     :"161209"=>22251}],
 "key_3"=>
   [{:book=>"abc",
     :trade_id=>"125",
     :ccy=>"eur",
     :mtm=>1908055,
     :"161205"=>-23279,
     :"161206"=>-730,
     :"161207"=>-513,
     :"161208"=>19933,
     :"161209"=>-21555}]}
```

The problem I am running into is that I can't seem to access the nested hash. I would like to be able to drill into the hash...so something like this...

```
p h.select { |key| key == "key_3" } [ :ccy, :mtm " ]
```

would give me an output like...

```
[{"eur","1908055"}]
```

I would also like to be able to do things like aggregation across the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a['key_3']               # [{:book=>"abc", :trade_id=>"125", :ccy=>"eur", :mtm=>1908055, :"161205"=>-23279, :"161206"=>-730, :"161207"=>-513, :"161208"=>19933, :"161209"=>-21555}]
  .first                 # {:book=>"abc", :trade_id=>"125", :ccy=>"eur", :mtm=>1908055, :"161205"=>-23279, :"161206"=>-730, :"161207"=>-513, :"161208"=>19933, :"161209"=>-21555}
  .values_at(:ccy, :mtm) # ["eur", 1908055]
#=> ["eur", 1908055]
```

## EDIT

To traverse the hash and map by nested key use [Enumerable#`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
a.map { |_k, v| v.first[:mtm] }
#=> [2000000, -150000, 1908055]
a.map {|k, v| v.first[:"161205"]}
#=> [-5045, 5178, -23279]
```

P.S.

`{"eur","1908055"}` is not a valid object in Ruby.

Comment: That works! Thanks. Is it possible to use a similar method to access all the keys and pull the data?

Comment: This is great but for some reason it won't work for me...once I add in [:mtm], for example, I get an error about from (irb):650:in `block in irb_binding'...maybe I can't use it in irb? If I do this a.map { |_k, v| v.first } it prints the whole map.

Comment: @antimuon it should in irb, pry and elsewhere. Double check spelling :)

Comment: I think I know what I did wrong...I tried to 'lookup' more than one value such as v.first[:book, :mtm]...I extended it using                                           var.map { |_k, v| v.first.values_at(:book, :mtm) } to return more than one value. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Iterate over all the keys, books and attributes :

```
h.each do |key, books|
  puts key
  books.each do |book|
    # Use values_at to define variables
    name, trade_id, price, currency = book.values_at(:book, :trade_id, :mtm, :ccy)

    puts "#{name} : #{price} #{currency} (#{trade_id})"

    # or iterate over all key/values :
    book.each do |attribute, value|
      puts "#{attribute} : #{value}"
    end

    puts
  end
end
```

It outputs :

```
key_1
abc : 2000000 usd (123)
book : abc
trade_id : 123
ccy : usd
mtm : 2000000
161205 : -5045
161206 : 600
161207 : 494
161208 : -2646
161209 : -231

key_2
abc : -150000 gbp (124)
book : abc
trade_id : 124
ccy : gbp
mtm : -150000
161205 : 5178
161206 : 20669
161207 : -18771
161208 : 214
161209 : 22251

key_3
abc : 1908055 eur (125)
book : abc
trade_id : 125
ccy : eur
mtm : 1908055
161205 : -23279
161206 : -730
161207 : -513
161208 : 19933
161209 : -21555
```

## Get one value, nested in the Hashes/Arrays :

That's a perfect job for [dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) if you're using Ruby 2.3 :

```
h.dig("key_3", 0, :ccy) # => "eur"
h.dig("key_3", 0, :mtm) # => 1908055
```

It "drills" through Hashes and Arrays, and you don't have to worry about errors if an object isn't found :

```
h.dig("key_4", 0, :ccy) # => nil
```

You can combine it with [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [`&.`](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) for a safe navigation and multiple values. No exception should be raised if an object isn't found :

```
h.dig("key_3", 0)&.values_at(:ccy, :mtm) #=> ["eur", 1908055]
price, currency = h.dig("key_3", 0)&.values_at(:mtm, :ccy)
price # => 1908055
currency # => "eur"
```

Comment: dig is good, but AFAIK won't do to return values at multiple keys (`:ccy, :mtm...`)

Comment: True. I updated the example with `&.` and `values_at`. Thanks.

Comment: I am using 2.25 so I can't use dig but I will check out with 2.3.

Answer (score -2):

Your inside hash is inside an array.

`first` will gets the first element of the array

`h['key_3'].first.values_at(:ccy, :mtm)` can work.